# mysql Wrong bytesec: 0-0-0 at linkstart: 0

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

I have several MySQL (MyISAM) tables that have been corrupted. Running CHECK TABLE mytable returns:

> +-----------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------- |
>
> clldata.mytable | check | warning  | Table is marked as crashed
>
> clldata.mytable | check | warning  | Size of datafile is: 4654864 Should be: 4602520
>
> clldata.mytable | check | error    | Wrong bytesec: 0-0-0 at linkstart: 0
>
> clldata.mytable |
> check | error    | Corrupt
> |
> +-----------------+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------+

4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

Running REPAIR TABLE mytable results in truncating about 90% of the rows that were originally in the table (and the size of the .MYD file also shrinks about 90%). And most of the remaining rows in mytable are clearly actually from one of the other corrupted tables.

Is there any hope of recovering data from such a table?

Comment: I am pretty sure you have yesterday's backup

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.